# Tried to git merge --ff-only, was rejected; then git merge did a fast-foward(?)

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

Still learning GIT. Tried to sync my local repos with commit done on 'central repos' style remote repos. First step was fetch origin:

```
git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From ssh://github.com/XXXXXX/ZZZZZZZZ
   bc2afff..3b3c8ee  master     -> origin/master
```

Then checked status and branch.

```
git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

git br
* master
```

Then tried to --ff-only.

```
git merge --ff-only origin master
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

Ok, so do a non-ff merge:

```
git merge origin master
Fast-forwarding to: origin
Already up-to-date with master
Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.
```

Checked the commit:

```
git show 4cbd3
...snip...
Merge branch 'master', remote-tracking branch 'origin'
```

It appears that a non-ff merge was done. The output from the merge 'Fast-fowarding to: origin' is what is confusing -- what is it trying to tell me? What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike e.g. `git push`, `git merge` does not take the name of a remote as an argument, so when you say `git merge origin master` you're actually saying "do an octopus merge from the 'origin' and 'master' branches". What you should've run is this:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Apparently you have a branch named "origin". Should it be there, or did you create it by mistake?

I'm not sure why you get inconsistent behavior between `git merge origin master` and `git merge --ff-only origin master`, but that doesn't really matter.